# Can't debug my app because have only first line for debug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging

on this screen you can see 1 line for breakpoint and 9 line for breakpoint.
Why i can't debug another lines?

[image: on this screen you can see 1 line for breakpoint and 9 line for breakpoint]

Comment: same here. Anyone?